# Bluetooth not detected in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Dell Inspiron 1720

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a super old laptop Dell Inspiron 1720. I am having issues with the bluetooth as it is not detected as shown below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4BnX.png)

The output of `lsusb` lists a bluetooth device as below

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

But the command `hcitool dev` does not show any device. Can you please help me with this issue?

**Update**

The output to `dmesg | grep -i blue` is as below

```
[  166.859023] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  166.859052] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  166.859058] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  166.859060] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  166.859064] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

I also looked for `rfkill list` and here is the output

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited and updated the question as you suggested.

Comment: See e.g. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2410564

Comment: @Pilot6, thank you. I tried following the instructions on that thread but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I use those command to solve this problem:

$ sudo apt-get install blueman

$ sudo blueman-manager

Then click device which you want to connect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).