# Bluetooth not working (Dell Inspiron 15 5000)

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, dell

I have a problem with my Dell Inspiron 15 5000, which is the bluetooth is not detected for some reason. I can't switch on the bluetooth. Actually my problem is similar with this case: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490047/bluetooth-not-working-on-dell-laptop and [Bluetooth not detected in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Dell Inspiron 1720](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233201/bluetooth-not-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-on-dell-inspiron-1720)

> Previously, my bluetooth worked well. But, for some while this problem is happening again & again, and I just restart my laptop and it works again. But now, it doesn't work even though I restart my laptop.

[image: screenshot]

```
➜  ~ rfkill 
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

also check with bluetoothctl;

```
➜  ~ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

and then;

```
➜  ~ dmesg | grep -i 'firmware\|blue'
[    0.149493] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    6.262277] dell_wmi: firmware scancode 0x48 maps to unrecognized keycode 0xffff
[    6.262278] dell_wmi: firmware scancode 0x50 maps to unrecognized keycode 0xffff
[    6.459574] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin (v1.9)
[    6.537118] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    6.740110] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 42e41877
[10844.973418] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[10844.973444] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[10844.973447] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[10844.973449] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[10844.973451] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[10916.088299] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[10916.088300] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[10916.088303] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[11331.091588] Modules linked in: bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc ccm aufs overlay nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_hda_codec_generic snd_sof snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec nouveau snd_hda_core uvcvideo snd_hwdep snd_pcm ath10k_pci i915 videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi ath10k_core videobuf2_v4l2 crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event mxm_wmi ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel ttm snd_rawmidi videobuf2_common ath
➜  ~ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

and my lsusb;

```
➜  ~ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:671e Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Someone suggested to following this commands, but I'm not sure it working for Dell Inspiron 15 5000, which is it mentioned for XPS version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1
```